# Karma will not run headless for ng test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Using Angular CLI: 1.6.6 and Angular 5, I can not get my unit tests to run on a headless Ubuntu server.

I keep getting:

```
20 03 2018 16:51:19.719:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

In my karma config I have:

```
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadless: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: [
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      // Without a remote debugging port, Google Chrome exits immediately.
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
    ],
  }
},
```

For my browser installed on the headless server:

```
one@work:~/github$ which google-chrome-stable
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

I have karma-chrome-launcher installed globally also, but not sure if it is needed.

Could it be Karma is looking for the wrong filename of the browser? I didn't find any directive to specify filename for the browser.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: You ever worked it out? i am in the very same shoes, except mine says `Connected on socket RsiL_ynCeo93MWLpAAAA with id 9953069` but never runs tests

Answer (score 2):

You are missing  the browsers configuration . In order to  make it work you need to set  "browswers" to "Chromeheadless" like this:

```
customLaunchers: {
    ChromeHeadless: {
      base: 'Chrome',
      flags: [
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
      ]
    }
  },
  browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
  singleRun: false
```

I hope this helps you!,

Juan

Comment: My config was just like this and I am still not able to connect